# Highchart: Ceiling and Max

Tags: highcharts

What is the difference between ceiling and max properties in highchart Axis? If I put ceiling 10 and max 5 or max 10 and ceiling 5, they give same result. Then why they are two different properties?

Answer (score 5):

we can say some thing like following:

> **ceiling** is `max-height`
>
> **max** is `fixed height`

Check **[THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3tFr8/)** and modify it to understand that what I say...

Comment: I didn't see the difference, could you elaborate more about it?, please

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the smaller (max or ceiling), it's not auto-adjusted,
[image]

The maximum height is 100, it's auto-adjusted,
[image]

The height is fixed at 100,
[image]